# Perforce install ,client unknown

Tags: ubuntu, perforce

guys,
after i set everything correctly,i have suffered question with client unknown when run the command like "P4 sync ".
so what's wrong with me,I  don't figure out with myself!!!

Answer (score 1):

Before you can sync files (e.g. transfer files from the perforce server to your local disk) you need to define **what** you want to sync.
You do that by setting up a workspace (aka client) specification.
That's described in the [perforce user guide](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-17566).
You can also do that via the Perforce GUI tool [P4V](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/helix-visual-client-p4v).

Comment: Run `p4 client`.